# Using loops in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, while-loop, joptionpane

I am trying to create an application that asks the user to choose an option and if they choose option 1 the following conditions should apply:

1. Ask the user how many tasks they want to enter
2. Create a loop that will display the tasks based on the amount entered by the user
3. Ask the user for task description
4. The task description should not exceed 50 characters if so an error message should display

Below is the code that I already have and I am struggling to display he number of tasks and task description

```java
package javaapplication4;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame details = new JFrame();
    Task task = new Task();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to MyWorld");
    String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(details, "Choose one of the following: \
        n " +
        "1. Add tasks \n" +
        "2. Show report \n" +
        "3. Quit \n"
    );

    int x;
    x = Integer.parseInt(option);
    if (x == 1) {
        String task1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(details, "Number of tasks:");
        Integer.parseInt(task1);
        String desc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Task Description:");
        while (!task.checkTaskDescription(desc)) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(details, "Enter description");
        } else if (x == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(details, "Coming Soon");
        } else if (x == 3) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public class Task {
    boolean checkTaskDescription(String taskDescription) {
        boolean length = false;
        if (taskDescription.length() == 10) {
            length = true;
        } else {
            length = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your specific problem? Also, be more clear when describing a question. You can't "use loops in JOptionPane", you can use JOptionPane while using loops, as you are doing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a debugger on your code, you will be able to easily find problems like this in the future.

Take a look at your `checkTaskDescription` method.

```java
      boolean checkTaskDescription(String taskDescription){
         boolean length= false;
         if(taskDescription.length() == 10) {
            length= true;  
         }else{ 
            length= false;
         }
         return false;
      }
```

So first, you create a variable called `length`, which is a `boolean`. Then, if the length of the given `taskDescription` is of proper size, you set `length` to be `true` or `false`. After you are done checking what the proper answer should be, you `return false;` anyways!

I assume you wanted to do `return length;`?

Comment: or: return taskDescription.length() == 10;

Comment: @Stultuske you are correct. I'm surprised I didn't think of that